# Apache Redirect to static location

Tags: apache, redirect

I need to do a redirect on any url from one domain to a one static url on another domain
example:

```
http://myexample.com -> redirect to http://example.myexample.com
http://myexample.com/example -> redirect to http://example.myexample.com
```

I have seen a lot of example where the redirect carries over the /example to the redirect site.

I DO NOT want this...I need any urls from one sight regardless of parameters to redirect to:

```
http://example.myexample.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should be straightforward, see below:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^myexample.com$
RewriteRule ^ http://example.myexample.com/? [R,L]
```

This will redirect *anything* hitting `myexample.com` regardless of the path to `http://example.myexample.com/`

Comment: It does not seem to work. http://myexample.com/example redirects to http://subdomain.myexample.comexample/...it seem to be carrying /example onto the end of the redirect...i then get a page not found...these are not on the same domains or subdomains i am just using example and myexample as placeholders

Comment: Do you have any other rules in the file? No way the rules above alone can be doing that.

Comment: This all thats in my sites-enabled config...<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
    RewriteRule ^ http://dashboard.example.com/ [R,L]

</IfModule>

Comment: Do you have any .htaccess files in the site anywhere? Has to be something else somewhere. Note I've now made a small amendment to the answer to strip any querystring too.

Comment: i am testing, but in my apache2.conf i have commented out #AccessFileName .htaccess...i still get http://example.myexample.comexample/...I think that stops all .htaccess from being loaded

Comment: This works..seems like there is a bug in the Chrome Browser..very weird